# numpy shorthand for taking jagged slice

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, array-broadcasting

I have an operation that I'm doing commonly which I'm calling a "jagged-slice" because I don't know the real name for it. It's best explained by example:

```
a = np.random.randn(50, 10)
entries_of_interest = np.random.randint(10, size = 50)  # Vector of 50 indices between 0 and 9
# Now I want the values contained in each row of a at the corresponding index in "entries of interest"
jagged_slice_of_a = a[np.arange(a.shape[0]), entries_of_interest]
# jagged_slice_of_a is now a vector with 50 elements.  Good.
```

Only problem is it's a bit cumbersome to do this `a[np.arange(a.shape[0]), entries_of_interest]` indexing (it seems silly to have to construct the "np.arange(a.shape[0])" just for the sake of this).  I'd like something like the `:` operator for this, but the `:` does something else.  Is there any more succinct way to do this operation?

### Best answer:

No, there is no better way with native numpy.  You can create a helper function for this if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is combersome only in the sense that it requires more typing for a task that seems so simple to you.

```
a[np.arange(a.shape[0]), entries_of_interest]
```

But as you note, the syntactically simpler `a[:, entries_of_interest]` has another interpretation in `numpy`.  Choosing a subset of the columns of an array is a more common task that choosing one (random) item from each row.

Your case is just a specialized instance of

```
a[I, J]
```

where `I` and `J` are 2 arrays of the same shape.  In the general case `entries_of_interest` could be smaller than `a.shape[0]` (not all the rows), or larger (several items from some rows), or even be 2d.  It could even select certain elements repeatedly.

I have found in other SO questions that performing this kind of element selection is faster when applied to `a.flat`.  But that requires some math to construct the `I*n+J` kind of flat index.

With your special knowledge of `J`, constructing `I` seems extra work, but `numpy` can't make that kind of assumption.  If this selection was more common someone could write a function that wraps your expression

```
def  peter_selection(a,I):
   # check the a.shape[0]==I.shape[0]
   return a[np.arange(a.shape[0]), I]
```

Comment: I thought it was short enough that I could get by without testing it in an Ipython session. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think that your current method is probably the best way.

You can also use [`choose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html) for this kind of selection. This is syntactically clearer, but is trickier to get right and potentially more limited. The equivalent with this method would be:

```
entries_of_interest.choose(a.T)
```

Comment: We discovered in another SO question that `choose` is limited to 32 items, that is `a.T.shape[0]` can't be larger than 32.  e.g. `N=32;np.arange(N).choose(np.arange(N*N).reshape(N,N))`

Comment: Ah, I was aware of some limitations with `choose` but couldn't quite remember what they were (I don't use it a great deal). I suppose this is because `choose` is implemented using the multi-dimensional iterators which place a limit of the number of dimensions an array can have.

Comment: I handn't noticed this before, but there's a note at the end of `choose` doc that says, in effect, this use of the function works, but it is considered to be an `abuse`.  `choices` should be, and be thought of as, a sequence, a list or tupe.

Comment: I also hadn't noticed that subtlety. I guess then that `choose` is useful mainly for simplifying multi-dimensional fancy indexing on small arrays, or for cases where the indexing/selection needs to be modified using the `mode` kwarg. Straightforward fancy indexing remains the best solution for cases like the OP's.

Answer (score 1):

The elements in `jagged_slice_of_a` are the diagonal elements of `a[:,entries_of_interest]`

A slightly less cumbersome way of doing this would therefore be to use [`np.diagonal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) to extract them.

```
jagged_slice_of_a = a[:, entries_of_interest].diagonal()
```

Comment: Ah.  Nice, but it seems to come at a cost of building a huge array for the intermediate step.  Or is it just a view?

Comment: Ahh you are correct - it does create the intermediate array not just a view so this method isn't particularly efficient.