# How to select values in a n-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have been trying to perform a simple operation, but I can't seem to find a simple way to do it using Numpy functions without creating unnecessary copies of the array.

Suppose we have the following 3-dimensional array :

```
In [171]: x = np.arange(24).reshape((4, 3, 2))
In [172]: x
Out[172]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[ 6,  7],
        [ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]],

       [[12, 13],
        [14, 15],
        [16, 17]],

       [[18, 19],
        [20, 21],
        [22, 23]]])
```

And the following array :

```
In [173]: y = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0])
```

I want to select in `x`, for each row, the value of the last dimension whose index is the corresponding element in `y`. In other words, I want :

```
array([[ 0,  2, 4],
       [ 7,  9, 11],
       [13, 15, 17],
       [18, 20, 22]])
```

The only solution that I have for now is using a for loop over the first dimension of `x` and `y`, as follows :

```
z = np.zeros((4, 3), dtype=int)
for i, row in enumerate(x):
    z[i, :] = row[:, y[i]]
```

Is there a way of avoiding a for loop here, using numpy functions or fancy indexing?

Thanks!

Comment: Your `y` array is 1D, not 2D (affects the title also).

Comment: See also the current SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735987/numpy-shorthand-for-taking-jagged-slice

Comment: I will gladly update the title, I didn't know how to explain it... Do you have a suggestion? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tricky aspect is that you don't want all of the 0th-dimension for each slice, you want the slices to *correspond* to each element in the 0th-dimension.  So you could do something like:

```
>>> x[np.arange(x.shape[0]), :, y]
array([[ 0,  2,  4],
       [ 7,  9, 11],
       [13, 15, 17],
       [18, 20, 22]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will have to read more about it... When first reading your answer I thought that it would give the same result than using : for the 0th-dimension, and I had to test out your solution to convince myself!

Answer (score 1):

Fancy indexing:

```
x[np.arange(y.size),:,y]
```

gives:

```
array([[ 0,  2,  4],
       [ 7,  9, 11],
       [13, 15, 17],
       [18, 20, 22]])
```